# Material icons not getting displayed properly in Angular 8

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I'm trying to learn Angular. In that, I have a requirement to develop a Material Tree in Angular 8.
I've been trying to run this example, based on Angular 7...on my local Angular 8 setup:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-nested-material-tree?file=app%2Fdemo.html

...but instead of getting the tree like this:
[image]

...its getting rendered like this for me:
  [image]

Any clues, what I'm missing and where?
(My code is a ditto copy-paste from the StackBlitz example, except that my package.json has Angular 8 libraries)

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the fonts into your index.html file

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```